# Simple method is called again once completed

Tags: c#, performance

**Background:**

I have a method that does some processing that I would like to be called over and over again. The method can take between 50 - 200 ms to complete.

Currently I have a `System.Timers.Timer` that calls the method when it elapses every 250 ms. I feel I I can make this more efficient by having the method "trigger" itself once it has completed.

Notes:

- Performance is key.
- Two of these methods should not be called at the same time, or overlap.

I would like avoid simply using a `while` loop that calls the method. It should call itself asynchronously perhaps using an event?

**Question:**

How can I have the method "trigger" itself once it has completed?

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid just using an infinite loop?

Comment: if <condition> {recursive_call()}

Comment: What's the problem with the while loop? It sounds like a simple optimal solution.  You'll be adding complexity for no reason otherwise.

Comment: My program does other processing, while this method polls hardware. If using a while loop would this be done in a different thread? If so could you show a simple example. Thanks.

Comment: I seems like a pretty silly feeling. I would only give it merit with some benchmarks: unlike the UI timer, it doesn't need to use the windows message queue. The "most efficient" would be `while(shouldContinue) { DoTheMethod() }` in a thread -- but is this *really* what is wanted? (And if it is, why use a Timer to begin with?)

Comment: @Nate: Without tail call optimizations, you'd eventually get a StackOverflowException going that way - especially if you go recursive every 200ms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform your `while` loop in a separate thread of execution, as long as you take the necessary multi-threading precautions with things such as locks, condition variables, wait handles, and the like.

- C#'s [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) could be suited to this job. But as Reed said, be sure to use the [LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) creation option. There's an example of this method posted by Reed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438389/simple-method-is-called-again-once-completed/7438538#7438538).
- Or use a [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) object directly. SLaks posted an example of this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438389/simple-method-is-called-again-once-completed/7438433#7438433).

If you're working with a WinForms application, you may want to look into using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: You should not consume a ThreadPool thread forever; the ThreadPool is meant for short tasks.

Comment: Yeah, I would just put the while loop IN the method. Fire it off on a separate thread once. Use a CancellationToken if you need to stop it.

Comment: @SLaks: The TPL would be fine for this - but the task should have the `LongRunning` hint applied.

Comment: @Reed and Ryan I like the idea of running a task. Could you show some simple code to get me started? Thanks.

Comment: Note that a Task will also run on a separate thread.  It would look just like my code, but in a `Task` rather than a `Thread`.  **It will still need to be thread-safe**.

Comment: @Ryan R: My answer shows the way this would typically be done via the TPL using a Task.

Comment: @SLaks: He's currently using a `System.Timers.Timer`, so he should already have the required synchronization in place...

Comment: Thanks @Ryan S for the answer. Can you put a link to [Reed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438389/simple-method-is-called-again-once-completed/7438538#7438538) and [SLaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438389/simple-method-is-called-again-once-completed/7438433#7438433) implementations mentioned below. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan R, All set. Hopefully this will help others in the future. Reed and SLaks both provided excellent examples.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new thread that continuously calls your method in a `while` loop.

```
void DoBackgroundPolling() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            YourMethod();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            log error
        }
    }
}

new Thread(DoBackgroundPolling).Start()
```

If you want to be able to control the polling, you can check a boolean field in that method.

Comment: I will be storing a lot of variables from the data that I polled. Are there any precautions I should take since this is running in a separate thread?

Comment: @Ryan: Definitely.  A full discussion of thread-safe development is beyond the scope of this comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've asked @Ryan S to link your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(void);

void MyMethod()
{
  do stuff;
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(MyMethod), null);
}
```

Comment: He wants to run in the _background_.

Comment: Where does it say that? He currently runs it on his foreground thread, calling it with a timer. Nowhere did he mention multithreading or running in the background, only that he wants it to run as soon as the previous call finishes.

Comment: See his comment on the question.

Comment: Actually all the other processing is done in the foreground, but I think it might be better to run this polling method in the background.

Comment: From what I can tell, he's just saying that he doesn't want to lock the main thread with an infinite while forever, which is quite reasonable. Queueing his method with a dispatcher will allow the main thread to do other work, thus avoiding the problem presented by using a loop. He can even adjust the priority to his liking, all the way down to ApplicationIdle.
edit: Don't get me wrong, I think running a background while loop is the best solution, provided there aren't any big synch problems that would have to be resolved, but I think this is a viable solution, given that he didn't want loops.

Comment: @Egor Yes you are correct. I do not want the infinite loop to affect the other processing. Using your solution, how quickly after the method finishes will the dispatched invoke the method?

Comment: It depends on the priority you set in the BeginInvoke call and how many other items are queued up. It's hard to tell, but you can certainly experiment by setting up a timer from the begin invoke call to the method execution. If you set the priority very high, it shouldn't be too long. Check out the msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This could be handled fairly cleanly using the TPL.  In your main thread, you could start this task in the background via:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Factory
      .StartNew(() => PollHardware(cancel.Token), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
      .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                var aggException = t.Exception; // Keep task from pulling down AppDomain
                // Log/handle/etc
                LogException(aggException.InnerException);
            }
        });
```

Then, all you need is a method to handle your loop:

```
void PollHardware(CancellationToken token)
{
     while(true)
     {           
         token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
         YourMethod();
     }
}
```

When you want the polling to stop, you can just call: `cancel.Cancel()`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will have to investigate my thread safeness.

Comment: @Ryan R: It introduce any **new** thread safety concerns, since your existing code is using a background thread (Timer's tick event is on a thread pool thread).  That being said, any data being shared with the main thread needs synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've asked @Ryan S to link your TPL implementation.